# Reading numbers from a space delimited text file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to read a file "parameters.txt" from the working directory.

This is parameters.txt:

```
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 3.14159 1.57079 0.001 10.0
```

I want to input each of these numbers into a vector "data"

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    ifstream fin("parameters.txt");
    vector<double> data(8);

    int element;
    while (fin >> element) {
        data.push_back(element);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << data[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

However, when I run the code, and try to output data, I get:

```
00000000
```

as an output.
What is the problem?

Comment: If you are reading doubles, `element` should also be a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reserve elements before inserting them, to make your code more efficient, you can use

```
vector<double> data;
data.reserve(8);
//push_back as you did
```

This creates an empty vector and sets the capazity to 8 elements.
You can also omit the reserve, than it will be done for you, but not in one step.

Also note that you can replace the last for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << data[i];
}
```

by a range-based for-loop, because the index is not necessary:

```
for (double i : data) {
  cout << i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 3 bugs:

1. you creating vector with 8 zero values at start: `vector<double> data(8);`, later you are adding new values at the end
2. Your variable `element` has `int` type, so `fin >> element` will read only `1` from text file leaving `.0` for further reading. During next iteration reading of `int` will fail since dot is encountered.
3. You code always prints 8 values from vector (so if file opening failed and problem `1` is fixed you will have undefined behavior).

The solution is:

```cpp
int main() {
    ifstream fin("parameters.txt");
    vector<double> data;

    double element;
    while (fin >> element) {
        data.push_back(element);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        cout << data[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/1CvTf7YY89C6hUyh

Which can be simplified to this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    ifstream f{"parameters.txt"};
    vector<double> v{istream_iterator<double>{f}, {}};
    
    for (auto x : v) {
        cout << x << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pcxz4gPakXwhzzvl

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<double> data(8);
```

You defined data as vector of double type with 8 items that they initiated by `double` default `0.0`! So using `push_back` will increase vector size and inserts at new index! So `data[0]` to `data[7]` stills are `0`!

You can try

```
vector<double> data(8);
int index = 0;
while (fin >> element && index < 8)
{
    data[index] = element;
    ++index;
}
```

Other problem! your file contains double values! So how you read them as int!
such `int element; fin >> element`?

modify code as below to work properly!

```
double element;
int index = 0;
while (fin >> element && index < 8)
{
    data[index++] = element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
vector<double> data(8);
```

does not set the initial *capacity* of the vector, it create a vector with *n* initial default-constructed elements. Then you're pushing new values to the end of that vector. When you output the first *n* elements of the vector you are only getting those initial elements.

And, your input statement is inputting into an `int` variable which you're then storing into a vector of doubles.

Also your output statement does not add any spaces, so your zeros are all mushed together.

Answer (score 0):

change **int element** to **double element**

```
int main() {
ifstream fin("parameters.txt");
vector<double> data(8);

double element;
while (fin >> element) {
    data.push_back(element);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    cout << data[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: This still suffers from the other bug of using `push_back` after resizing to 8.